# WebSocket vs socket io in react native location tracker app

Tags: react-native, websocket, socket.io

React native support websocket according to [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network), But another alternative is socket IO... I want to build a location tracker app (Like Uber) with react native, It seems that socket IO has overhead when compared to websocket (more server requests, bigger library size , ...) but has nice features like auto-reconnecting when interrupted (which happens on mobile networks). What do you think about this two options (socket IO and websocket) and which is better for a location tracker app?

Answer (score 2):

*Please note that I believe your question is wrong here on stack overflow as it its nature if more of a discussion type. Maybe consider asking it somewhere else*

You can think of it this way, websocket is just the mere protocol while socket.io is a library using that protocol.

Just like it is much harder and more work to write a proper web server with the standard library in node (http package) versus using something like express, it is much harder to implement websocket properly without a library like socket.io

socket.io will do a lot of heavy lifting for you in this example, many things you had to implement yourself to be on par. In that sense it socket.io means less overhead not more (for everything more that a simple hello world request)